# Why we need Jackson api for JSON Response View in Spring MVC

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Currently I was looking for an example Spring MVC with JSON response view, most of the examples talks about Jackson API for JSON Response view. I couldn't understand why we need Jackson API for returning the response as JSON. Is there any other way to return JSON view in the response? And also I do not understand when we are using Jackson how view it is getting rendered as JSON Array values in response. Could somebody let me where we can get a clear idea on it.

Comment: @erhun Hi, I just wanted to let you know that I rolled back your edit, because it didn't improve anything. Adding inline code formatting is for code, not for technical words like JSON and Spring MVC.

Comment: @ProgramFOXOk Thanks for information, i learned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use Jackson API for your Spring MVC project, to me easiest one is `JSONObject`  this is the [source](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples) and some examples [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) You can easily create Json object and parse it via this way.

```
JSONObject sessionJSonObj =new JSONObject().put("session", "session") ;
String sessionJSonObj = (JSONObject) querySessionJSonObj.get("session");
```

> And also I do not understand when we are using Jackson how view it is
>   getting rendered as JSON Array values in response?

Actually `JACKSON` present you an API you can easily do your `JSON` operation with it like `JSONObject`, `GSON` or other `JSON APIs`. Other APIs also have this kind of capabilities for array operation or other data types.

Comment: Thanks a lot erhun :) but I have not used any session to store and retreive it, I have used @ResponseBody annotation to return it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

As erhun said, you don't need Jackson API. In fact Spring MVC will use Jackson libs only if it finds them on the classpath.

When you're using the *@ResponseBody* you're saying that the return value of the method is serialized directly to the body of the HTTP Response. What follows is that an appropriate *HttpMessageConverter* implementaion converts the returned type to the negotiated content type.

Spring provides you with the full flexibility in configuring which converter will be in charge for conversion. The following [blog post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) describes how you can configure your own custom converter. The explanation is for a custom XML converter, but analogous for any content-type